# HTML-JavaScript-Nested_Loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops

Bros,

i am trying to write codes about a double-nested-Loop of JavaScript in HTML , that would like to be showing some pictures base on the order .
Let's say ...

i get a one dimention array:

```
var numArray = [88, 5, 700];
```

and then
i tried the code below ,
but only show 1 pic ,
what did i miss ?

```
<img class="test" id="1">
...
<img class="test" id="99">

<script>
var numArray = [88, 5, 700];
for (var k = 0; k <= numArray.length; k++) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i <= 9999; i++) 
    {
        var temp = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[i].id;
        if (temp = numArray[k] ) 
            {document.getElementById(temp).src = "http://picid="+temp+".jpg";}
            else
            {document.getElementById(temp).display = "none";}
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This does not  look right `"http://picid="+temp+".jpg"`

Comment: `if (temp = numArray[k] )`  is an assignment not a test for equality

Answer (score 0):

So you have 99 images and you want so change the source of the images in the array and hide the rest?

```
for (var k = 0; k <= numArray.length; k++)
```

would overflow the array, it would need to be from 0 to k < length, not <= length

```js
const numArray = [88, 5, 70]; // not 700 I assume
const images = document.getElementsByClassName("test")
for (var i = 0; i < 99; i++) { // from 0 to 98 is 99 images
  let temp = images[i].id;
  let image = document.getElementById(temp);
  if (numArray.includes(temp)) { // not =  - that is assignment
    image.src = temp + ".jpg";
  } else {
    image.style.display = "none"; // style.display
  }
}
```

but this is shorter

```
const numArray = [88, 5, 70]; // not 700 I assume
[...document.querySelectorAll("test")].forEach((img, i) => {
  if (numArray.includes(img.id)) img.src = img.id + ".jpg";
  else img.style.display = "none"; 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use backticks on this:  {document.getElementById(temp).src = 'http://picid${temp}.jpg';}